# Error using ^ Inputs must be a scalar and a square matrix. To compute elementwise POWER, use POWER (.^) instead

Tags: matlab

I am trying to create plots using this code:

```
ms = 0.47675;

mp = 0.00095;

d = 0.2990;

g = 9.81;
l = 0.579;

R = [0.515 0.437 0.361 0.283 0.203 0.1209];

theta=[0.1585 0.1325 0.1090 0.0870 0.0615 0.0360];

T = [1.234 1.232 1.231 1.233 1.230 1.230];

M=ms+mp;

for  y=1:length(R);
    l(y)=(1/12)*ms*l^2+ms*d^2+mp*R(y)^2;
    h(y)=d*(1-cos(theta(y)));
    w(y)=sqrt(2*M*g*h(y)/l(y));
    vp(y)=(2*g*M*d*T(y)*sin(theta(y)/2))/(mp*R(y)*2*pi);
    pf(y)=mp*vp(y);
    pe(y)=M*d*w(y);
    Ee(y)=M*g*h(y);
    Ef(y)=(mp*vp(y)^2)/2;
    Ediff(y)=Ee(y)-Ef(y);
    pdiff(y)=pe(y)-pf(y);

end

plot(R,Ediff '*')

title'skillnad mellan 'totala energi f?re och efter st?t'

xlabel 'Avst?nd mellan pilens tr?ffpunkt och rot.axel(m)'

ylabel "\Delta'E(J)'

axis ([0 0.6 -0.4 -0.3])
```

But i keep getting the error:

> Error using  ^  Inputs must be a scalar and a square matrix. To
>   compute elementwise POWER, use POWER (.^) instead.

Please if someone could help me and tell me whats wrong with my code

Comment: The error tells you what to do..... use `.^` (element-wise operation)

Comment: l(y)=(1/12)*ms*l^2+ms*d^2+mp*R(y)^2;

Check your use of "l" above -- which started out as a scalar -- so l^2 would be fine for first and second iterations. After second iteration, l became a vector (size = 2) -- thus l^2 won't work. As Suever suggested, ".^2" would normally fix this, but I think there is more that you should do to fix your code. You could use debugging (http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/debugging-process-and-features.html) to see the errors.

Comment: This may be of use, https://www.mathworks.com/help/pdf_doc/matlab/getstart.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here: http://au.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/11845-trouble-with-basic-plotting

The '^' operator tells MATLAB to do the operation once, which it can't do on a matrix. The '.^' operator tells MATLAB to do the operation on every element in the matrix.